# How encrypt GKE secrets using Customer supplied keys

Tags: security, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-secrets

I have created a gke cluster without any encryption flag to encrypt. How can i encrypt the secrets in gke using custom keys not using Cloud KMS. How can secure the kubernets secrets

Comment: So you do not want to use Cloud KMS but you want to use BYOK?

Comment: Yes, generally EncryptionConfiguration and --encryption-provider-config flag is used for K8s on host machine. Is there any possibility to do same in gke